# BigQuery select multiple tables with different column names

Tags: google-bigquery, union, wildcard

Consider the following BigQuery tables schemas in my dataset my_dataset:

- Table_0001: NAME (string); NUMBER (string)
- Table_0002: NAME(string); NUMBER (string)
- Table_0003: NAME(string); NUMBER (string)
- ...
- Table_0865: NAME (string); CODE (string)
- Table_0866: NAME(string); CODE (string)
- ...

I now want to union all tables using :

```
select * from `my_dataset.*`
```

However this will not yield the CODE column of the second set of table. From my understanding, the schema of the first table in the dataset will be adopted instead.

So the result with be something like:

```
| NAME  | NUMBER | 
__________________
| John  | 123456 |
| Mary  | 123478 |
| ...   | ...... |
| Abdul | null   |
| Ariel | null   |
```

I tried to tap into the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` so as to select the two sets of tables separately and then union them:

```
with t_code as (
    select
       table_name, 
from my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where column_name = 'CODE'
    ),

select t.NAME, t.CODE as NUMBER from `my_dataset.*` as t
where _TABLE_SUFFIX in (select * from t_code)
```

However, still the script will look to the first table of my_dataset for its schema and will return: `Error Running Query: Name CODE not found inside t`.

So now I'm at a loss: **How can I union all my tables without having to union them one by one?** ie. how to select CODE as NUMBER in the second set of tables.

*Note: Although it seems [the question was asked over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370500/search-multiples-tables-with-different-column-names-for-a-string), the accepted answer did not seem to actually respond to the question (as far as I'm concerned).*

Comment: so you have two different schemas - do you know which range belong to which schema? like for example: Table_0001 to Table_0864 have one schema and Table_0865 and above have another schema? or it is unknown?

Comment: The actual range isn't as clearly noted as in my example. The name of tables actually differ within the set. I simplified the example for this OP.

Comment: the only way is to build dynamically union of all tables and the execute it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  should be simple - but if you see this will satisfy you and you still will need help - let me know

Comment: If I would use execute immediate, it could not be saved as a view right? I'd have to run a single query and store results in a table for further use?

Comment: correct. you will not be able to save it as a view. but you will be able to save it as a table

Answer (score 1):

The trick I see you can do is to first gather all codes by running

```
create table `my_another_dataset.codes` as 
select * from `my_dataset.*` where not code is null
```

Then to do any simple fake update of any just one table with `number` column - this will make schema with `number` column default. so now you can gather all numbers

```
create table `my_another_dataset.numbers` as 
select * from `my_dataset.*` where not number is null
```

Finally then you can do simple union

```
select * from `my_another_dataset.numbers` union all
select * from `my_another_dataset.codes`
```

Note: see also my comment below your question

Comment: In the first bit, `select * from 'my_dataset.*' where not CODE is null` won't work. It will throw an error saying that CODE isn't a recognized name.

Comment: so do in opposite direction! start with numbers and then with codes!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

borrow.id AS `borrowId`,
IF(borrow.created_date IS NULL, '', borrow.created_date) AS `borrowCreatedDate`,
IF(borrow.return_date IS NULL, '', borrow.return_date) AS `borrowReturnDate`,
IF(borrow.return_date IS NULL, '0', '1') AS `borrowIsReturn`,

IF(person.card_identity IS NULL, '', person.card_identity) AS `personCardIdentity`,
IF(person.fullname IS NULL, '', person.fullname) AS `personFullname`,
IF(person.phone_number IS NULL, '', person.phone_number) AS `personPhoneNumber`,

IF(book.book_name IS NULL, '', book.book_name) AS `bookName`,
IF(book.year IS NULL, '', book.year) AS `bookYear`

FROM tbl_tbl_borrow AS borrow

LEFT JOIN tbl_person AS person
ON person.card_identity = borrow.person_card_identity

LEFT JOIN tbl_book AS book
ON book.unique_id = borrow.book_unique_id

ORDER BY
borrow.return_date ASC, person.fullname ASC;
```